# Trying to make 24 V switch using IRFZ44N MOSFET and an Arduino

Tags: arduino, mosfet

I’m trying to make a 6 channel circuit using MOSFETs and an Arduino. What I’m trying to control is the musical horn which has 6 switchable air horns. I am trying to control each switch air horn on and off using an Arduino. I am using IRFZ44N MOSFETs and 10 kΩ resistor to turn on the air horns, but  the MOSFET is getting hot using 24 V. Can someone tell me the proper circuit for making the 6 channel circuit using MOSFET? Note that the supply power is using 24 V because the horn requires 24 V to turn on.

Here is the reference circuit I am using:

[image]

[image]

and heres the example of product, it using transistor D880, i think the problem is because im not using diode
[image]

Comment: What is the output voltage from pin of arduino, 5v or 3v3? What is the current draw of horn?

Comment: Probably too high Vgsth on your MOSFET. Please measure the Vgs and Vds on it when turned on (before it gets too hot).

Comment: @MichalPodmanický the output voltage from the arduino on pin is 5v i guess, and the horn voltage required 24v to turn on. Current itself im not sure but right now im using adaptor with 5Ampere for the moment

Comment: @winny VGS 5V and VDS 24V

Comment: Then your MOSFET has either out of spec high Vgsth or is broken.

Comment: @winny after realizing i think i need diode, because switch air horn itself does not have positive and negative pole. it can work both ways

Comment: FYI, D880 is probably a 2SD880 NPN transistor.

Answer (score 3):

It should work with an [IRLZ44](https://www.vishay.com/docs/91328/irlz44.pdf) rather than a IRFZ44  (assuming a 5V-out Arduino as shown in your pictorial).

[image]

The IRFZ44 needs 10V to fully turn on, which would add a lot of complexity to your circuit.

You might also want to put a reverse-biased rectifier diode across each coil.

I hope this thing is to be used in a land far, far away.

Comment: im a starter not sure what to do ive try to add capacitor and resistor and still not change

Comment: Spehro is saying that you should use a different model of transistor.  The one you are using does not fully turn on at 5V, so its "on" resistance is too high and that's why it's getting hot.  24V isn't the problem here, it's that 5V at the gate is too low to control the IR**F**Z44 transistor properly.  But the IR**L**Z44 would work at 5V.

Comment: i think the problem is the diode itself

Comment: Well, now I don't understand why you came here at all, if you already think you have the key to your problem.

Comment: Also, the "reverse-biased rectifier diode" he mentions is often called a "flyback diode".  It's purpose is to protect the MOSFET when it turns off, because the current flowing in the load coil will cause a large voltage spike (called "back EMF") that can damage the MOSFET.  The diode should be placed in parallel with the load, with its arrow "pointing up" towards the power supply.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyback_diode